# Mathematica is saying both inequality are false

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, inequalities

I'm trying to ask Mathematica to compare 2 different values in inequality but it keeps saying "False". I put the code I'm running below. Thanks in Advance for any hint on what is problematic in my writting !

```
Reduce[{(a^2 c1 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ1 - 
       a^2 s θ3)/(4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b c3 + 4 c1 c3 + 
       4 b s θ1 + 4 c3 s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
       4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) > q, a > 0, 
   1 > p > 0, s > 0, 1 > b > 0, 
   0 > θ1 > θ2 > θ3 > 1, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, 
   c3 > 0}, {c2, c3}] /. 
 q -> (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(4 b^2 + 
     4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 4 c3 s θ2 + 
     4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ2 θ3)

(*False*)
```

Comment: I think you left out some code at the start. Are you trying to `Reduce`?

Comment: Yes indeed sorry it missed a part of the code that I just replaced. I'm indeed trying to `Reduce`.

Comment: That's the issue: `0 > \[Theta]1 > \[Theta]2 > \[Theta]3 > 1 `  , a typo. Zero is not greater than one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense now for the False !

Comment: The issue can too be `0 > \[Theta]1 > \[Theta]2 > \[Theta]3 >- 1 `. That much less effort and a closer match to an error.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting

```
0 > θ1 > θ2 > θ3 > 1
```

Which cannot be, as you are asking the numbers to be smaller than 0 and larger than 1 at the same time.

Correct form should be:

```
 1 > θ1 > θ2 > θ3 > 0
```

Which gives as an answer:

```
0 < p < 1 && 0 < θ2 < 1 && θ2 < θ1 < 1 && 0 < θ3 < θ2 && c1 > 0 && s > 0 && 0 < b < 1 && a > 0 &&  0 < c2 < c1 + s θ1 - s θ2 && c3 > 0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   0 > θ1 > θ2 > θ3 >- 1

Reduce[{(a^2 c1 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ1 - 
       a^2 s θ3)/(4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b c3 + 4 c1 c3 + 
       4 b s θ1 + 4 c3 s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
       4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) > q, a > 0, 
   1 > p > 0, s > 0, 1 > b > 0, 
   0 > θ1 > θ2 > θ3 > -1, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, 
   c3 > 0}, {c2, c3}] /. 
 q -> (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(4 b^2 + 
     4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 4 c3 s θ2 + 
     4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ2 θ3)

(0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 
   0 < b < 1 && 
   0 < s < -(b/θ3) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) <= -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > 0) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   0 < s < -(b/θ3) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && -(a^2/(4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) < (
    a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   0 < c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s == -(b/θ3) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) <= -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > 0) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s == -(b/θ3) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) > -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && c2 > 0 && 
   0 < c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 
   0 < b < 1 && -(b/θ3) < 
    s <= -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   0 < c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 
   0 < b < 1 && -(b/θ3) < 
    s <= -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > -b - s θ3) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 
   0 < b < 1 && -(b/θ3) < 
    s <= -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) <= (
    a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) <= -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > -b - s θ3) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 
   0 < b < 1 && -(b/θ3) < 
    s <= -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > 0 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) > -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && 
   c2 > 0 && -b - s θ3 < 
    c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   0 < c1 < -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   0 < c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   0 < c1 < -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > -b - s θ3) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   0 < c1 < -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) <= (
    a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) <= -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > -b - s θ3) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   0 < c1 < -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) > -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && 
   c2 > 0 && -b - s θ3 < 
    c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   0 < c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) + (
       4 s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 <
     0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) < (
    a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > -b - s θ3) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c1 + 4 b s θ1 + 4 b s θ3 + 
     4 c1 s θ3 + 4 s^2 θ1 θ3) <= (
    a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) <= -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && c2 > 0 && 
   c3 > -b - s θ3) || (0 < p < 1 && -1 < θ1 < 
    0 && -1 < θ3 < θ1 && 0 < b < 1 && 
   s > -(b/θ1) && θ3 < θ2 < θ1 && 
   c1 > -b - s θ1 && 
   a > 0 && (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3)/(
    4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
     4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
     4 s^2 θ2 θ3) > -(a^2/(
     4 b + 4 c1 + 4 s θ1)) && 
   c2 > 0 && -b - s θ3 < 
    c3 < (a^2 c1 + a^2 s θ1 - a^2 s θ3 - (
       4 b^2 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b c1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ1 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 b s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 c1 s θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3) - (
       4 s^2 θ1 θ3 (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - 
          a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 + 
        4 s^2 θ2 θ3))/(a^2 + (
       4 b (a^2 c2 - a^2 c3 + a^2 s θ2 - a^2 s θ3))/(
       4 b^2 + 4 b c2 + 4 b c3 + 4 c2 c3 + 4 b s θ2 + 
        4 c3 s θ2 + 4 b s θ3 + 4 c2 s θ3 +
```